# Law of total expectation and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, expectation

We know from law of total expectation that 
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]=\mathbb{E}[Y]
$$
Does that still work if there is a further condition, i.e. does this equation hold?
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]|Z=z]=\mathbb{E}[Y|Z=z]
$$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{E}[(Y|Z=z)|X]$?!

Comment: @heropup FWIW, I am not aware of any meaning of the notation $E[E[(Y\mid Z=z)\mid X]]$ you introduced in your first comment and of any mathematical text where it would be used. Conditional expectations being a subject notoriously hard to grasp, I find detrimental to add confusion by introducing undefined and personal notations as if they were standard.

Comment: @heropup Because there is no such thing as a random variable $W=(Y\mid Z=z)$.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not. A counterexample would be $Y=Z$, $X$ independent of $Y$. Then $
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]] = \mathbb{E}Y$,  $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]|Z=z] = 
\mathbb{E} Y,$$ $$\mathbb{E}[Y|Z=z] = z.$$

Of course, we need $Y$ to be non-degenerate.

Comment: Indeed, the proper application of the tower rule is that: $$\mathsf E[Y\mid Z{=}z]=\mathsf E[\mathsf E[Y\mid X,Z]\mid Z{=}z]$$